Given $|ax^2+bx+c| \le |x|^3$. Prove that $a=b=c=0$
Let $a, b ,c$ be fixed real constants and suppose that for every real $x$:
$|ax^2+bx+c| \le |x|^3$. Prove that $a=b=c=0$
Author suggests to use the Squeeze Theorem in the solution, it is stated as follows:
TH. 1 :
Let $f, s, g$ be three functions and suppose that there is $\epsilon \gt 0$ s.t.
$f(x) \le s(x) \le g(x)$ for $|x-p|< \epsilon$. Under these conditions,
$\lim \limits_{x \to p} f(x) = L =$ $\lim \limits_{x \to p} g(x)$ $\implies$ $\lim \limits_{x \to p} s(x)=L$
My attempt:
Note that $-|x|^3 \le |ax^2+bx+c| \le |x|^3$, and then
$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} -|x|^3 =$ $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} |x|^3 $ $\implies$ $0 \le |c| \le 0$ $\implies$ $c=0$.
Then i can rewrite the the latter quadratic equation as $|ax^2+bx|$ which has roots $r_1=0$ and $r_2= -\frac{b}{a}$.
$r_1 + r_2 = -\frac{b}{a}$ $\implies$ $a=b$. Then i only need to show $a=0=b$

You just show that $c = 0$, which leaves the original inequality becomes
$$
    \vert ax^2 + bx \vert \le \vert x \vert^3 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
For $x \neq 0$, divides both side by $\vert x \vert > 0$ to get
$$
    \vert ax + b \vert \le \vert x \vert^2 \ \forall x \neq 0
$$
Take $x \rightarrow 0$ to get $b = 0$. To prove $a = 0$, we do similarly.

The proof can be made purely algebraic. We start with a theoretical background. Let  $p(x)$ is a nonzero polynomial, i.e. not all its coefficients are $0.$ Assume $a$ is a root of $p(x).$ Then $p(x)$ is divisible by $x-a.$ The root $a$ is of order $k$ if $p(x)$ is divisible by $(x-a)^k$ and not divisible by $(x-a)^{k+1}.$ This implies that if $|p(x)|\le |q(x)|$ and $a$ is a root of order $k$ of $q(x)$ then $a$ is a root of order at least $k$ of $p(x).$ Moreover $k\le \deg p.$
In the OP case $0$ is a root of order $3$ of $q(x)=x^3.$ Hence $0$ is a root of order at least $3$ of $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c.$ In view of the first part this is impossible for a nonzero polynomial $p(x)$ as $\deg p\le 2.$ Thus all three coefficients of $p(x)$ must vanish.
We may generalize the exercise in the following way: if $|p(x)|\le |q(x)|$ and $q(x)$ has $n$ roots $a_j$ of order $k_j$ respectively and $\deg p< k_1+\ldots +k_n,$ then all the coefficients of $p(x)$ must vanish.
